# RDLC Make Column colour same as colour in pie chart

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, pie-chart

I have a requirement in rdlc reports where we have to draw table and pie chart from the same datasource where we want to show colour in table column from pie chart.
I searched but did not find a way to do this. I have added a screenshot of our requirement.

[image]

Comment: In the chart properties, just use a custom palette and the set the colours in the same order. Note that the custom palette has to be defined for each chart if there are more than one, it's not a report level property.

Comment: Yes you are right that we can define colors by pallete but we also need to map those colors on table as well. any idea how can we acheive this.

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly..

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this. Either assign the colour in the dataset query and use that, so your dataset would look something like ...

```
AssetClass    Value    RGB
Stocks        123      #FF0000
Cash          5678     #0000FF
```

In the cells you want to colour set the `background color` property to something like `=Fields!RGB.Value`

... or you can use an expression in the cells directly, something like

```
=SWITCH (
         Fields!AssetClass.Value = "Stocks", "#FF0000",
         Fields!AssetClass.Value = "Cash", "#0000FF",
         True, Nothing
        )
```

**Note** This is done from memory so may not be 100% accurate but should be close enough for you to progress.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please mark the answer as accepted as this will help others looking for a similar answer in the future.

Comment: I tried to mark this answer but it is saying that minimum 15 points required. So cannot market this as accepted.